# looking for the distributed / parallel processing software?

Tags: distributed

I have 1 PC, 1 iMac and 5 laptops and use only 1 or 2 at a time. My hobby is developing web, video/audio editing. So when `encoding videos`, I would like to assign other laptops for `parallel processing` to reduce the total encoding time.

Is there any software that will share the processing load like `distributed software`? I have not found one yet.

Comment: You would most likely need a specialized video encoding program. I don't think it's possible to distribute the CPU workload of *any* arbitrary external program.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [Compressor](https://www.apple.com/uk/final-cut-pro/compressor/) can use distributed rendering very simply, just by adding them to a list in Prefs - but only to other Macs.

I don't know of anything cross-platform.